# Is there a way to list NetBeans editor hints?

Tags: java, netbeans, warnings

Does NetBeans have a way to show all the editor hints (like missing braces, unused imports, etc.) for a project? Ideally, they would show up in the Task List, but the warning icons in the project view would be fine too.

Right now, the best I can do is to open each file and look at the color indicator next to the scrollbar.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As of NetBeans 7.2, there's a new "Inpect" window (go to `Source > Inspect`...) that will show all the hints for a project. You can also install additional inspectors, like FindBugs, and those hints will be included too.

Comment: This is actually only in NetBeans 7.2 or higher, which is in Release Candidate as of this comment.

Comment: @JakeKing Oops, I found it when I was trying out 7.2, but I thought I saw that it was added in 7.1.

Answer (score 3):

**Window --> Action Items** will show you errors, warnings, and user-generated todo items.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the **Tasks** window.

To open the window, click menu **Window** → **Tasks**.

You can choose to look at the tasks/hints/errors for the

- file that you are currently editing
- the main project (and the projects that it depends on)
- all projects open in the IDE

Comment: I can't get it to show hints though, just warnings, errors, and TODO comments.

Comment: There is an issue for this... http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=151760

Comment: Tasks wont lists code hints like code improvement suggestions