# How to show up compiler errors/warnings list in NetBeans 7.2 for C/C++?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.2

Where can I find the window where the compiler errors/warnings were listed in NetBeans 7.2 for C/C++?
I saw that maybe the Action Items window would make the job, but it doesn't.
(I use MinGW suite with MSYS.)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't as it's stated here http://forums.netbeans.org/topic52174.html But as it's suggested in the post, you can make a request for the feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to list NetBeans editor hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293408/is-there-a-way-to-list-netbeans-editor-hints)

Answer (score -1):

The output window is displayed automatically when you run the project. But if you don’t see it select “Window > Output > Output” or press Ctrl+4[image]

Comment: This is the output of the program. The question is about the compiler error output, which I couldn't find either, so far ...