# View all lines that have a specific warning

Tags: java, netbeans

In Netbeans, there is a warning "Field hides another field". How do I view all lines that have this warning? I tried searching at Window->Action Items but the said warning is not there. Also tried searching this on the net, but I can't seem to find a resolving instruction.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to list NetBeans editor hints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293408/is-there-a-way-to-list-netbeans-editor-hints)

Answer (score 1):

You mean where it shows it like it does when you forget a semi-colon?

Try going to: Tools->Option->Editor->General->Field hides another field and set as "Error" in the drop down box.

EDIT:
Another thing I found that might help is going to: Source->Inspect
Some other plugins like FindBugs might also help.

Comment: Hi Devon, I was hoping for a list display of these warnings. I want Netbeans to list down the lines that contain the error, say in the Action Items window. Do you have any idea? Your answer is still useful by the way. Thanks.

Comment: @bimboxX I don't have any other ideas, maybe try the Netbeans documents? I'll do a search just now

Comment: @bimboxX Updated it with something that also may help

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. I also tried the updated answer out, but the hint did not show up on the inspection list. Probably, I'll have to install a new inspector.